# Can the calamity cause more than one extras to be brought back?

Tags: another

Could a student and a teacher that died in previous years be brought back at the same time because of the calamity of Class 3-3?

Comment: By logic, the curse was born when one particular person died, so the "extra" will be only one although multiple people can die in yearly cycle.